# Java command not found error when running .java file from command line in MacOS

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

This is the first time I tried running .java files from Terminal, so please be patient with me. Basically, I cd'd to the src folder that contains java files, then I typed this:

```
$ ./javafile.java
./javafile.java: line 1: import: command not found
./javafile.java: line 2: import: command not found
./javafile.java: line 4: public: command not found
./javafile.java: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./javafile.java: line 6: `  public static void main(String[] args) '
(base)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Java is not an interpreted language and can not be run like a executable (like that). Question 1: What version of Java are you using? Question 2: Do you just want to run the code, or do you want to distribute the program? Traditional answer: Compile the .java file to a .class with the java compiler (`javac`). Then use the Java Runtime Environment to execute it (`java`). Step 1: `javac javafile.java` Step 2: `java -cp . javafile` - note that this still will not work unless `javafile` contains a class named `javafile`. Without seeing your code or knowing the environment, can't really say more.

Comment: if you have recent enough java installed (check with `java -version`, the version should be "11.something" or greater) and your app is a single file, you can run it like this: `java javafile.java`; but @ElliottFrisch is right, without knowing details of your project it’s hard to help more than this. I think we could start with answers to _“do you have more code than a single file?”_ and _”does your code require libraries?”_